# Converting Datetime from an int to an actual date

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

```
test_dates = list(data_S['datetime'])
```

test_dates prints:

```
1608271200000.0
1608530400000.0
1608616800000.0
1608703200000.0
1608789600000.0
1609135200000.0
1609221600000.0
1609308000000.0
1609394400000.0
1609740000000.0
1609826400000.0
1609912800000.0
1609999200000.0
1610085600000.0
1610344800000.0
1610431200000.0
1610517600000.0
1610604000000.0
1610690400000.0
1611036000000.0

for var in test_dates:
    updated_dates = []
    new_vars = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(var/ 1e3)
    updated_dates.append(new_vars)
   

print(updated_dates)
```

This prints:

```
[datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 18, 22, 0)]
```

My question is, how come it doesn't print out a list of the converted Timestamps? I thought that it would print:

```
[2012-03-15 17:00:00, 2012-03-16 17:00:00, 2012-03-17 17:00:00]
```

And so on.

Comment: You're resetting `updated_dates` to an empty list each pass through the loop.

Comment: Wow, that was my bad. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try replacing this line:

```
updated_dates.append(new_vars)
```

With:

```
updated_dates.append(str(new_vars))
```

Because if you call `str` it would become the actual date format. It can do it because it uses the class `__str__` and `__repr__` magic methods.

If you don't use `__str__` and/or `__repr__` in a class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, blah):
        self.blah = blah
a = Foo(123)
print(a)
```

It would give:

```
<__main__.Foo object at 0x000000B785154160>
```

Not the actual value, to return the value you would have to do:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, blah):
        self.blah = blah
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.blah
a = Foo('abc')
print(a)
```

Which outputs:

```
 abc
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the format more when appending it as an str